# persistent vti configuration in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

How to translate this command:

```
ip link add name vti1 type vti key VTI_KEY local LOCAL_IPv4_ADDR remote REMOTE_IPv4_ADDR
```

into persistent config in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-vti1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet from the **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-tunnel** script

```
# Create the tunnel
# The outer addresses are those of the underlying (public) network.
/sbin/ip $proto tunnel add "$DEVICE" mode "$MODE" \
    ${MY_OUTER_IPADDR:+local "$MY_OUTER_IPADDR"} \
    ${PEER_OUTER_IPADDR:+remote "$PEER_OUTER_IPADDR"} \
    ${KEY:+key "$KEY"} ${TTL:+ttl "$TTL"}
```

Your "MODE" will likely be "IPIP".